# Add specific ports to Centos firewall

Tags: centos7, firewalld

I am fairly new to Centos/Linux and have been trying to configure my firewall to restrict access to mysql and ssh for only a few IP addresses. When I run the following and do a port scan I do see that all ports are shut, however when I run firewall-cmd --reload port 22 opens again. How can I restrict it by default or do I not need to run the reload? What would happen if the server restarted? Thanks.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source=IP1/24
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source=IP2/24
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-service=mysql
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-service=ssh
firewall-cmd --list-services --zone=trusted
firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-service=ssh
```

Comment: Which zones did you assign to each interface?

Comment: If there is a command to tell you that I will happily run it :)

Comment: @Ukuser32 `firewall-cmd --get-zone-of-interface=<interface_name>` or the reverse : `firewall-cmd --zone=<zone_name> --list-interfaces`

Comment: @Ukuser32 Did you copy/paste or modified with zone/interface name ? If it's the second answer, then firewalld is not using any interface on your machine and you need to bind interfaces to target zones.

Comment: I did copy/paste/modify the code so it looks like the later. How does one bind interfaces to target zones?